# how to disable the checkbox if the checkbox is hidden

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dropdown menu and based on selection in dropdown menu i show a checkbox.

so i am able to achieve this. But when i once choose that option where i need to show checkbox and i check the checkbox then if i select the option which will not show the checkbox then i still see the value true on button click. How do i solve this?

Code:

```
<label *ngIf="selectedTemplate.name == 'A'" class="container">
              <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="IsChecked" data-md-icheck />
              <span class="customFontAgHeader">Include A</span>
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
```

So on button click i still see that ischecked as true because previously i had selected true and then i changed the dropdown option so i want to make it unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

in .html

```
<select (change)="onchanged()">
        --------------
    </select>
```

in ts

```
onchanged()
{
  this.IsChecked = false
}
```

or else (edit)

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="IsChecked" #filterName data-md-icheck />

<select (change)=" filterName.value = false ">
            --------------
        </select>
```

Comment: is it possible to do without that? Something directly from HTML?